# Como executar uma procedure oracle via c# sem retorno de dados?

Tags: c#, oracle, procedure

estou desenvolvendo um WEBAPI em c# que executa uma procedure no Oracle e após esse procedimento,
ele consulta uma tabela. Essa procedure apenas deleta dados de uma tabela temporaria e insere o
os dados  informados na mesma e em seguida exibe eles com mais algumas informações.
Quando executo diretamente no Oracle a procedure ela funciona: (execute Minha_procedure(CHAVE, ANO,MES)).
obs: Ela tem um cursor.
Porém no meu código não está executando, Segue abaixo meu método:

```
public void ExecutarProcedure(string chave, string mes, string ano)
    {
        OpenConnection();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("BDRH_APPS.SP_CARGA_SITE", Con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("CHAVE_PAR", chave);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ANOFOLHA_PAR",ano );
        cmd.Parameters.Add("MESFOLHA_PAR",mes );

        // execute the command to open the ref cursors
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           


        cmd.Dispose();

        CloseConnection();

    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: não dá erro, simplesmente não está dando o execute na procedure no banco

Comment: OracleCommand has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260

Comment: Mas o problema parece ser na gestão da conexão, o que faz o método `OpenConnection();` e de onde vem o atributo `Con`?

Comment: Se não da erro mas também não "executa", pode ser que falta fazer commit. Difícil dizer...

Comment: Leandro, essa classe herda de uma outra classe de conexão com o banco  protected OracleConnection Con;    //Conexão com a base de dados..
        protected OracleCommand Cmd;       //Executar comandos SQL..
        protected OracleDataReader Dr;     //Ler dados de consultas..
        protected OracleTransaction Tr;    //transações (commit/rollback)

Comment: sem ver essas outras não tem como ajudar, mas ainda acho que você não está executando o comando na conexão aberta... apresente um um [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver! Criei um cursor de saída no oracle (prc out sys_refcursor) e consegui trazer os dados.

Obrigado à todos!